# Does ExoPlayer create a windowIndex for each media source in ConcatenatingMediaSource?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I'm working on an app that streams a list of mp3 files, to do this I've used ExoPlayer with a `ConcatenatingMediaSource` as this:

```
private fun createMediaSource(
        tracks: List<Track>
    ): MediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource(true).apply {
        tracks.forEach { track ->
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource
                .Factory(DefaultDataSourceFactory(context))
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(track.getFullUri()))
            addMediaSource(mediaSource)
        }
    }
```

This works great, the files play as list with no errors at all, however what's required from me is to play all these streams as a single stream, where I show the total length of all streams on the seek bar, and the user would seek seamlessly between them.

Of course I'm not using the VideoPlayer provided by ExoPlayer because I need the seekbar to span all media sources, which apparently this is not possible to do with ExoPlayerUi.

So this is the logic I've used when the user tries to seek:

```
             exoPlayer.apply {
                var previousTracksLength = 0L
                var windowIndex = 0
                var currentItemLength = 0L

                run loop@{
                    tracksList.forEachIndexed { index, track ->
                        currentItemLength = track.getLengthMillis()
                        previousTracksLength += currentItemLength
                        if (newPositionMillis < previousTracksLength) {
                            windowIndex = index
                            return@loop
                        }
                    }
                }

                val positionForCurrentTrack = (newPositionMillis - (previousTracksLength - currentItemLength))

                pause()
                if (windowIndex == currentWindowIndex) {
                    seekTo(positionForCurrentTrack)
                } else {
                    seekTo(windowIndex, positionForCurrentTrack)
                }
                play()
            }
```

This works amazingly well when the ConcatenatingMediaSource has only 3 or less media sources, but if it's bigger than that, weird behavior starts showing up, I might just want to seek 10 seconds forward the player would move more than 2 minutes instead.

After debugging it was obvious for me that when I call: `seekTo(windowIndex, positionForCurrentTrack)` exoPlayer is seeking to a window that's not mapped with a specific media source in the ConcatenatingMediaSource !

And here comes my questions:

Does ExoPlayer create a single window for each mediaSource in the ConcatenatingMediaSource or not ?
and If not is there a way to force it to do that ?

Comment: "Does ExoPlayer create a single window for each mediaSource in the ConcatenatingMediaSource or not ?" It seems so, in our case we play clips from different videos and a window is created for each clip. Unfortunately, don't know how to force that :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but the explanation to why when I called `seekTo(windowIndex, position)` the player seemed like it was ignoring the windowIndex and actually seek to a completely unexpected position is because the media type was mp3 !

Apparently many devs have suffered the same issue where the player seek position is out of sync with the real position of the media that's being played when it's an mp3.

More details for anyone having weird issues when playing mp3 using ExoPlayer
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6787#issuecomment-568180969